# Ключевое слово class перед класс-мембером

Tags: c++

Считается ли ключевое слово ***class*** перед класс-мембером как своего рода forward declaration класса, чтобы компилятор не беспокоился, что за "идентификатор".

---

Идентичны ли эти фрагменты кода?

```
class Foo
{
private:
    class Bar* a;
};
```

и

```
class Bar;
class Foo
{
private:
    Bar* a;
};
```

Comment: нет это не одно и тоже в первом варианте попытка создать вложенный класс в области видимости другого класса, а во втором случае вы пытаетесь использовать уже готовый готовый класс через делигирование

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Да, идентичны.**

Согласно [3.3.2 Point of declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#7) [basic.scope.pdecl],
для таких объявлений, которые называются *elaborated-type-speciﬁer*, имя объявляется во внешней области видимости.

Это можно продемонстрировать таким кодом:

```
struct Foo {
    struct Bar* a;
};

struct Bar {};

int main() {
    Bar b;
    Foo f;
    f.a = &b;
}
```

Однако для объявлений вида `class name;`, имя объявляется в той же области видимости, например

```
struct Foo {
    struct Bar;
};

struct Foo::Bar {};
```

Comment: @diralik не нужно. Для целей демонстрации проще использовать `struct`, чтобы не заморачиваться с уровнями доступа к членам.