# class перед возвращаемым типом

Tags: c++

Зачем пишут `class` перед возвращаемым типом?

```
class first
{
};

class two
{
public:
    class first test();
};
```

Comment: покажите пожалуйста пример кода, когда действительно надо писать class

Comment: А где вы видите возвращаемый тип?...

Comment: не дописал скобки, была функция class first test();

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ключевое слово class перед класс-мембером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479813/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-class-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у Вас в одной области определен и класс, и одноимённая функция, то указание `class` необходимо для однозначного обращения к типу, а не к функции. Пример:

```
class A {};

void A() {}

int main()
{
    class A a; // здесь нужно class
}
```

В Вашем случае, наличие `class` не является обязательным.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ alexolut.

```
class A; // <- без этой строки не скопилируется. Это forward declaration
A* getA();

/// some code

class A {

};


A* getA() {
    return new A;
}
```

Однако для упрощения можно сделать forward declaration прямо в месте использования:

```
class A* getA();
```

Это часто бывает удобно при использовании внутри шаблонных параметров:

```
std::tuple<class A*, int, float> b;
```

Comment: С учётом вопроса уместнее был бы тип без `*`.

Comment: И мой ник немного иначе пишется :)

Comment: Без * нужно или ссылку юзать, или что-то шаблонное, для чего достаточно forward declaration (читай: использует внутри T*), поэтому решил с указателем всё же. Ник поправил, прошу прощения :)

Comment: для возвращаемого типа по значению можно использовать forward declaration. Проверьте сами.

Comment: @alexolut неожиданно. Хотя после некоторых раздумий становится понятно, почему. Спасибо.